# Java - How to apply a keyboard shortcut of 3 keys for a JButton?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcut

Currently i am using "Ctrl + Space" shortcut to fire a JButton event in my Java code like this :

```
this.getRootPane().registerKeyboardAction( addStudentButtonActionListener, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke( KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK ), JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW );
```

But i want to assign a shortcut of "Shift + Ctrl + Space" for this event instead. How can i do that ?

Comment: KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK | KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then use the following key stroke:

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE,
    KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK | KeyEvent.CTRL_MASK)
```

Comment: I have read this solution in another place, but it is not working ! ... When i press the 3 keyboard buttons nothing happens ! ... When i tried KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, KeyEvent.SHIFT_MASK ) pressing Shift+Space did nothing. I think the SHIFT_MASK is not working for some reason.

Comment: Maybe SHIFT+Space and SHIFT+CTRL+Space is reserved in your OS or in Swing. Try it with a different key like SHIFT+CTRL+E.

Comment: Actually it works fine. It was a problem in the focusing behavior. I was standing in a wrong place so the shortcut refused to work. When i fixed the focus issue it worked just fine. Thanks a lot icza.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the String format of the KeyStroke

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift ctrl pressed SPACE")
```

Example

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TestShiftCtrlSpace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                JPanel panel = (JPanel)frame.getContentPane();
                InputMap im = panel.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
                im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("shift ctrl pressed SPACE"), "scs");
                panel.getActionMap().put("scs", new AbstractAction(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        System.out.println("Shift + Ctrl + Space");
                    }
                });
                frame.setSize(300, 300);
                frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```