# How to detect 3 keyboard buttons in Swing?

Tags: java, swing, keystroke

I want to detect if the user has pressed a combination of 3 or more keyboard buttons in Java Swing. For example, if the user has used a combination like **Ctrl+Alt+R** or **Ctrl+Shift+Alt+R**.

So far what I found over the internet is mentioned below.

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)<br>{<br>
    AWTKeyStroke ak = AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStrokeForEvent(e);
    if(ak.equals(AWTKeyStroke.getAWTKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_F4,InputEvent.ALT_MASK)))
    {
        System.exit(0);          
    }
```

But the problem with the above code is that it works fine for a combination of 2 buttons only but not for 3 or more buttons.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: You can refer to this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25120254/java-how-to-apply-a-keyboard-shortcut-of-3-keys-for-a-jbutton

Comment: 1) *".. and if possible then give me a sample program for reference."* This is not the place to ask for sample code. 2) BTW - you realise that `Alt+F4` is the default close keys for a frame, right?

Comment: @Andrew: yeah I do. I mentioned it just to tell what all things I've tried so far for my problem.

Comment: `I mentioned it just to tell what all things I've tried so far` - well mention the actual code you want to use, not something that you expect to be overridden by the OS. The problem might be your keyboard. Cheaper keyboards may support the pressing of 4 keys at the same time. And frankly as a user I would never want to try that either. Keep the keyboard combinations simple so you don't have to be a contortionist to activate the keystroke.

Comment: @camickr: I have used the mentioned code to implement one of the functionality of my Application and also I want to detect 3 or 4 key combinations as a part of other functionality. And also there is nothing wrong with my keyboard or something but its more like I want to develop a functionality(s) that can be initiated with a combination of different keys of the keyboard.

Comment: You said the code works for 2 buttons, but not 3 or more, that is the sign of a keyboard problem. Post your [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Maybe people will test your code to see if they have a problem.

Comment: I mean I know what all methods are available to detect 2 buttons which is working fine but I want to detect 3 or 4 buttons for another functionality which I don't know. This is what I asked originally in the query.